# Restore output to notebook

Tags: printing, message-coding

While playing around in settings, I believe I did something to cause all output to be printed to a pop up window. How do I restore the output to the notebook where the evaluation occurs? In options inspector all of my settings seem to indicate that messages should print to console but I am unsure.

Comment: Just happened to me too, and I don't remember changing anything.  Weird!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What does:

```
CurrentValue[{MessageOptions, "KernelMessageAction"}]
```

> "PrintToNotebook"

return for you? If it is not "PrintToNotebook", try resetting it with:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {MessageOptions, "KernelMessageAction"}] = Inherited
```

> "PrintToNotebook"